# Uncaught TypeError: {variable} is not iterable

Tags: reactjs

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import StoryCircle from '../../Components/Story/StoryCircle'
import HomeRight from '../../Components/HomeRight/HomeRight'
import PostCard from '../../Components/Post/PostCard'
import { useDisclosure } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { findUserPostAction } from '../../Redux/Post/Action'

const HomePage = () => {
  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure()
  const [userIds, setUserIds] = useState()
  const {user, post} = useSelector((store)=>store)
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token")
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(()=>{
    const newIds = user.reqUser?.following?.map((user)=>user.id);
    setUserIds([user.reqUser?.id,...newIds])
  }, [user.reqUser])

  useEffect(()=>{
    const data = {
      jwt: token,
      userIds: [userIds].join(",")
    }
    dispatch(findUserPostAction(data))
  },[userIds, post.createdPost, post.deletedPost])

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="mt-10 flex w-[100%] justify-center">
        <div className='w-[44%] px-10 '>
          <div className='storydiv flex space-x-2 border p-4 rounded-md justify-start w-full'>
            {[1,1,11].map((item)=>(<StoryCircle/>
            ))}
          </div>

          <div className='space-y-10 w-full mt-10'>
            {post.userPost.length>0 && post.userPost.map((item)=>(
              <PostCard post={item}/>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='w-[35%]'>
          <HomeRight/>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  )
}

export default HomePage
```

The error I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: newIds is not iterable
    at HomePage.jsx:18:1
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:23150:1)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:24926:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js:24891:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24878:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:24866:1)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:27039:1)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:26984:1)
    at commitRootImpl (react-dom.development.js:26935:1)
    at commitRoot (react-dom.development.js:26682:1)
```

I've tried looking for answers, but none of them seem to work. I'm kind of new to React so I'm hoping to get an answer to this problem, but more importantly would like to know the concepts. If more info like code is needed for this let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Can you edit your question with a full error stack message?

Comment: As per the error you are trying to iterate over non-iterable itesm. It could be `setUserIds([user.reqUser?.id, ...newIds])`, where  `newIds` may not be an array. It could be `falsy` value which is not iterable. You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that people can understand your problem and help you.

Comment: @DecPK if `user.reqUser?.following?` is iterable in the line just before then `newIds` should be an array. so the error is in that line using `.map` on a non iterable variable

Answer (score 0):

variable is not iterable occurs when trying to loop through an array or any other iterable variable using a method, for example here:

```js
const newIds = user.reqUser?.following?.map((user)=>user.id);
```

you are trying to map through `user.reqUser?.following?` but its value is not iterable so at this point `user.reqUser?.following?` is not an array and most likely `undefined` it should have better if you have included more information, but you can add `console.log(user)` just before the line mentioned above add see what the user looks like when the component is first mounted and then each times that `user. reqUser` is updated and will understand when this happens.

Comment: I added console.log(user) but when I ran the react app, it stayed on the same runtime error.

Comment: and is `user.reqUser?.following?` an array?

Comment: Not sure where else to look other than the react app console which stayed on the error

Comment: you can see in the browser console

Comment: That was where I was looking. I expanded the list but didn’t see anything related to user that I can understand

Comment: try it this way: `console.log("user object is: ", user)` so you can find it easly other way the compiler didn't arrives at this point and the app crushes before

Comment: I did. reqUser returns null in the user reducer. And .following is from the backend of the project

Comment: @gzhe1056 that was obvious, now you know where is the real issue

Comment: So I checked my backend api and it turns out following returns an array. So I'm wondering what frontend changes could I make to fix the not iterable error

Comment: if `following` is an array so your code should work

Comment: Yes, it works now. I had to sign in in my app  because the backend auth wouldn't allow it.. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.